# Is it possible to improve quality of image using CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to improve quality of image using CSS when I use `background: url('image.png')`?

May be accept filter CSS?

Comment: What kind of quality are you talking about?

Comment: I mean definition of pixels

Comment: The image downloaded has a certain quality. You cannot "improve" that on the client side. An improvement means you have to add image information. Where should that additional information come from?

Comment: The only thing you _can_ do (and should!) is to offer multiple versions (resolutions) of the same image to the browser and enable it to pick the one that is most suitable for the current situation. That is a _very_ important aspect for responsive layouts that are requested on different devices. But that is more a server side offer from which the client side only "picks" the right choice. And that is not done by css, but by logic builtin to the browser itself. Nothing you want or should try to control.

Comment: @arkascha : It's better to design an image that fits all resolutions in some way. You cannot satisfy all screen resolutions so why the extra work? You wrote: "And that is not done by css, but by logic builtin to the browser itself." I'm sorry? The browser cannot guess for a lower or higher resolution, you must tell the browser to do it! What I suggest to do is using a big resolution and downsize the filesize by stripping file format overhead and/or reducing colors (png) or reducing quality invisible for the eye (jpg) if possible. A downscale looks always better than an upscale. Use css3 rules.

Comment: Sorry, but I dare to disagree with most of what you say. It certainly is _not_ better to use an image (how do you "design" an image btw?) in a single resolution, since that won't work in a satisfying manner. Your "in some way" does not help here (what does that mean _exactly_ anyway?). Why do you claim that I "cannot satisfy all screen resolutions"? Off course one can. That is exactly what todays image references _do_ allow. They allow _the client side_ to pick the most suitable resolution for the current situation. You really should take a look into things like `srcset` and the like.

Comment: This is a valid question. Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter property has the following functions:

1. none
2. brightness(%)
3. contrast(%)
4. drop-shadow(h-shadow
5. v-shadow blur spread color)
6. grayscale(%)
7. hue-rotate(deg)
8. invert(%)
9. opacity(%) 
   10.saturate(%)
10. sepia(%)
11. url()
12. initial
13. inherit
14. blur(px)

Each above function is self explanatory. Regarding the pixels, you can't really change it using the filter property. You can use `width` and `height` but It will change the size of the picture to appear on the webpage but not improving the quality.

Comment: I think `blur(px)` is the best option out of these, to sort of "hide" the fact that the image is low-res.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't any way to actually improve your image quality using css (that comes down to how your image file is saved originally), one trick I use at times is to force some extra anti-aliasing from the browser using `transform`

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.999);
  transform: scale(0.999);
```

This won't make your image noticeably smaller, but it should just be enough to get your browser to blur it a bit.

Comment: Problem with this is: page rendering stress, it can slow-down the page.